# Browser stops working after it tries to open the printer dialog box

Tags: google-chrome, browser, printer, crash, microsoft-edge

I submitted a University application, then it directs me to print it. When I click on the print button, the print dialog box is trying to appear on the browser (usually, I am not connected to the printer, so, I just save it as PDF through the print dialog box). But the dialog box never appears, and my browser stops working. I have to forcefully shut down my browser.

This happens with Edge and Google Chrome. I am using the updated versions of both.

Comment: All browsers or just Chrome and Edge? Is this page public to the world? If so providing link to the page in question might help others debug the issues.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 I tried only on Chrome and Edge. This issue is with every pdf link (say, https://www.berkshirehathaway.com/qtrly/1stqtr20.pdf). When I tried to print it, the browser stops working.

Comment: The same thing has happened to me. Chances are that it is the disk usage and the only real thing you can do it wait. Also, edge and chrome are both chromium based. Try something like firefox and see what happens